# c++ Tic-Tac-Toe program

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe

So I've been building a Tic-Tac-Toe program, it's still a work in progress at the moment. I'm not getting any build errors so far, but the main problem I've got at the moment is that the program just closes when player 1 enters their first number. I think it's because of the Input() function, but after looking through the code about 3 times, I've hit a blank and have no idea what's causing it. Here's the relevant code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


char acBoard[3][3] = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
char cPlayerCharacter = '0';
int iChoice = iChoice + 1;




void DisplayBoard()
{
    system("cls");
    cout << ' ' << acBoard[0][0] << " | " << acBoard[0][1] << " | " << acBoard[0][2] << endl;
    cout << "---|---|---" << endl;
    cout << ' ' << acBoard[1][0] << " | " << acBoard[1][1] << " | " << acBoard[1][2] << endl;
    cout << "---|---|---" << endl;;
    cout << ' ' << acBoard[2][0] << " | " << acBoard[2][1] << " | " << acBoard[2][2] << endl;
}

char win()
{
    if (acBoard[0][0] && acBoard[0][1] && acBoard[0][2] == 'X' ||
        acBoard[1][0] && acBoard[1][1] && acBoard[1][2] == 'X' ||
        acBoard[2][0] && acBoard[2][1] && acBoard[2][2] == 'X' ||
        acBoard[0][0] && acBoard[1][0] && acBoard[2][0] == 'X' ||
        acBoard[0][1] && acBoard[1][1] && acBoard[2][1] == 'X' ||
        acBoard[0][2] && acBoard[1][2] && acBoard[2][2] == 'X' ||
        acBoard[0][0] && acBoard[1][1] && acBoard[2][2] == 'X' ||
        acBoard[2][0] && acBoard[1][1] && acBoard[2][0] == 'X')
        return 'X';

    if (acBoard[0][0] && acBoard[0][1] && acBoard[0][2] == '0' ||
        acBoard[1][0] && acBoard[1][1] && acBoard[1][2] == '0' ||
        acBoard[2][0] && acBoard[2][1] && acBoard[2][2] == '0' ||
        acBoard[0][0] && acBoard[1][0] && acBoard[2][0] == '0' ||
        acBoard[0][1] && acBoard[1][1] && acBoard[2][1] == '0' ||
        acBoard[0][2] && acBoard[1][2] && acBoard[2][2] == '0' ||
        acBoard[0][0] && acBoard[1][1] && acBoard[2][2] == '0' ||
        acBoard[2][0] && acBoard[1][1] && acBoard[2][0] == '0')
        return '0';

    return 'd';
}


void Input()
{
    cin >> iChoice;
    switch (iChoice)
    {
    case 1:
        acBoard[0][0] = cPlayerCharacter;
        break;
    case 2:
        acBoard[0][1] = cPlayerCharacter;
        break;
    case 3:
        acBoard[0][2] = cPlayerCharacter;
        break;
    case 4:
        acBoard[1][0] = cPlayerCharacter;
        break;
    case 5:
        acBoard[1][1] = cPlayerCharacter;
        break;
    case 6:
        acBoard[1][2] = cPlayerCharacter;
        break;
    case 7:
        acBoard[2][0] = cPlayerCharacter;
        break;
    case 8:
        acBoard[2][1] = cPlayerCharacter;
        break;
    case 9:
        acBoard[2][2] = cPlayerCharacter;
        break;
    }
}


int main()
{
    do
    {
        DisplayBoard();
        cout << "Enter a Number Player " << cPlayerCharacter << ": ";
        Input();
        if (cPlayerCharacter = '0')
        {
            cPlayerCharacter = 'X';
        }
        else cPlayerCharacter = '0';
    } while (!win);

    if (win() == 'd')
    {
        cout << "It's a draw";
    }

    if (win() == '0')
    {
        cout << "Nought wins";
    }

    if (win() == 'X')
    {
        cout << "Cross wins";
    }
}
```

I feel like the solution's right in front of me but I just can't see it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you step through with a debugger you only have to look at it once.

Comment: `} while (!win);` That should have been a warning. Unless you turned the warnings down. win is a function.

Comment: Close voting as a typo. `!win` should be `!win()`.

Comment: IMHO the design is bad. Imagine what you'll have to do if you decide to change the game to be played on a 5x5 board.

Comment: @sasha199568 So I see a 5x5 board is actually [something that could happen](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/23548/whats-the-best-strategy-to-win-a-tic-tac-toe-variant-on-a-5x5-board)... :)

Comment: Any time your code starts to look like you keep cutting and pasting copies of the same code, it's time to take a step back and rethink the design.

Answer (score 2):

`while (!win);` should be `while (!win());` to actually call the function. otherwise you are essentially just evaluating whether or not the function exists.